Why a parameter value passing down from a parent component to child is more accurate than getting a parameter directly in a child itself
I'm working on a NextJS project and kind of confusing about the reason behind this behavior
Firstly, I've wrote a custom hook which return in what orientation should the content be displayed
export type TOrientation = "landscape" | "portrait";

export function useOrientation(): TOrientation {
  const [optimalOrientation, setOptimalOrientation] = useState<TOrientation >("landscape");

  useEffect(() => {
    const innerWidth = window.innerWidth;
    setOptimalOrientation(innerWidth >= 1920 ? "landscape" : "portrait");
  }, []);

  return optimalOrientation;
}

Now, I have a component named VideoPlayer that will render either 'main_video_landscape.mp4' or 'main_video_portrait.mp4' based on the value of optimalOrientation
Note: this component is a child component of another component and also get dynamically imported
export function VideoPlayer() {
  const optimalOrientation = useOrientation();

  return (
    <div>
      <video>
        <source
          src={
            optimalOrientation === "landscape"
              ? "/home/main_video_landscape.mp4"
              : "/home/main_video_portrait.mp4"
          }
          type="video/mp4"
        />
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
      </video>
    </div>
  );
}

And the parent component of VideoPlayer named Preview
const VideoPlayer = dynamic(
  () =>
    import("@/home/VideoPlayer").then((module) => ({
      default: module.VideoPlayer,
    })),
  { ssr: false }
);

export function Preview() {
  return (
    <section className="flex relative">
      <VideoPlayer />
    </section>
  );
}

The thing is, when the screen width is narrower than 1920px the optimalOrientation value is 'landscape' first and then becomes 'portrait' later, but the VideoPlayer doesn't change the rendered video from 'main_video_landscape.mp4' to 'main_video_portrait.mp4' as it should.
Things get weirder when I call the useOrientation() on the parent component and pass the value down to the child component, instead of calling the useOrientation() and get the value directly inside the child component. This works as I expected, main_video_portrait.mp4 is being shown.
const VideoPlayer = dynamic(
  () =>
    import("@/home/VideoPlayer").then((module) => ({
      default: module.VideoPlayer,
    })),
  { ssr: false }
);

export function Preview() {
  // Now calling the useOrientation() and passes the optimalOrientation to the VideoPlayer component
  const optimalOrientation = useOrientation();

  return (
    <section className="flex relative">
      <VideoPlayer optimalOrientation={optimalOrientation} />
    </section>
  );
}

export function VideoPlayer({optimalOrientation}: {optimalOrientation: TOrientation}) {
  return (
    <div>
      <video>
        <source
          src={
            // Now using the value 'optimalOrientation' getting passed from the 'Preview' instead
            optimalOrientation === "landscape"
              ? "/home/main_video_landscape.mp4"
              : "/home/main_video_portrait.mp4"
          }
          type="video/mp4"
        />
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
      </video>
    </div>
  );
}

My question is, what are the reasons behind this behavior. Why passing property to a child gives more accurate result.
My understanding is since the VideoPlayer is imported dynamically, it should be rendered on the client with the correct innerWidth. While Preview is rendered on the server so the innerWidth value shouldn’t be more accurate than the one get on the client component.
I'd be appreciated if you could provide me an explanation, document, video, or any learning sources related to this. Thank you in advance.
